# Is it possible for a view of a Rails application to have a controller from another application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have 2 Rails applications. One returns JSON from the database, the other is a client that uses the first application as data access. However, it is too slow. So we are looking for alternatives. In the future, there will be other clients that will use the application that returns JSON that's why we separated it.

It sounds crazy but I want to know if it possible for a view of a Rails application to have a controller from another application?

Comment: Do you mean Rails application? Why do you ask? You have to explain some more. Your question does not make much sense like this.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a rails application. Basically, we have 2 applications, one returns JSON from database the other one is a client that uses the first application as data access. However, it is too slow. So we are looking for alternatives.

Comment: In the future, there will be other clients that will use the application that returns JSON that's why we separated it.

Comment: I don't understand the remark about *why* you separated, but I think you should not have separated into two applications.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use a controller from another application. Based on your comments, I think you should have one application that returns either json or html. Rails already provides the functionality for this. E.g.:

Rails 3.0:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml { render :xml => @users }
      format.json { render :json => @users }
    end
  end
end
```

Rails 3.1:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with(@users)
  end
end
```

Source: [Embracing REST with mind, body and soul](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/)

Comment: Thanks Mischa. Actually, that is how we are doing it right now. We are formatting our returns with JSON. Works flawlessly.

However, another Rails application is using the first application (the one that returns JSON), it is basically a web client. We find it very slow. 

The reason why we separated them as two applications is because in the future there will be other clients that will use the first application as some sort of public API.

Comment: @jhoeforth - I see your problem. You don't want to copy your controller code for every new client. It may be a solution to extract your controller code into a gem and use that gem in every new application. Other than that I can't think of anything.

Comment: Sorry that the question is closed now. With your explanation I don't think it should have been closed.

Comment: It's fine. I should have been more forthcoming with my question's description. Oh well, thanks again.